# How to remove extra materials from a mesh if the mesh has more than 1 material?

Tags: python, materials, scripting

I am trying to write a little script that checks if mesh has more than one material, and if it does, remove materials until there is only one left on the item. Here is what I have so far:

```
import bpy
for ob in bpy.data.objects:
    number_of_mats = len(ob.material_slots.items())
    if number_of_mats > 1:
        for i in range(number_of_mats-1):
            # remove material here?
```

I cannot seem to figure out the method to remove a mat at this point. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the index of the list to `1`, iterate through the upcoming slots, call and [override the context](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6101/poll-failed-context-incorrect-example-bpy-ops-view3d-background-image-add/6105#6105) of [`material_slot_remove()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.object.html#bpy.ops.object.material_slot_remove). Demo on how to remove all *slots > 0*:

**Blender 3.2+**

```
import bpy
from bpy import context

for obj in context.selected_editable_objects:
    obj.active_material_index = 1
    for i in range(1, len(obj.material_slots)):
        with context.temp_override(object=obj):
            bpy.ops.object.material_slot_remove()
```

**Blender 2.8+**

```
import bpy

for obj in bpy.context.selected_editable_objects:
    obj.active_material_index = 1
    for i in range(1, len(obj.material_slots)):
        bpy.ops.object.material_slot_remove({'object': obj})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it without operators

```py
import bpy
for ob in bpy.data.objects:
    # Skip things without materials (armatures, etc.)
    if not hasattr(ob.data, 'materials'):
        continue

    while len(ob.data.materials) > 1:
        ob.data.materials.pop()
```

Answer (score 0):

When I remove a material in the ui, this is echo'd:

```
bpy.context.object.active_material_index = 2
bpy.ops.object.material_slot_remove()
```

[Looks like the documentation live here.](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.90/bpy.ops.object.html?highlight=material_slot_remove#bpy.ops.object.material_slot_remove)

Hope that helps,
Koen